# TikzCd: Midway label of a diagonal edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I have the following problem.
I want to label the edge of A and B with a letter f.
The thing is, if I use

```
\draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway]{$f$} (v2);
```

I get this:

[image]

And if I use

```
\draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway,above]{$f$} (v2);
```

I get this:

[image]

I want "f" to be at the place of the star * - in some positive distance perpendicular to the centre of A,B. But "midway" gives me f in the center of the line and "midway, above" gives me f that is little bit to the right. Similarly, "midway, left" gives me f that is below the star.

Is there a simple way to have f in the place of * ?

EDIT:
My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
\node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
\draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway,above]{$f$} (v2);
\node at (-2,1.4) {*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT2: Removed red crosses.

Comment: Welcome to TeXSX! Could you please pose a small compilable code reproducing the problem? This code does not seem to use tikz-cd.

Comment: Sure, just added it. And I just realized I've been actually using tikzpicture (sorry)!

Comment: This is not compilable as is. Everything with a red cross should not be in the figure?

Comment: Yes sorry to make this more confusing those red crosses shouldn't be there, I was using TizkEdt to display the diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! There are two solutions. The first is that you can simply use the `fill=white` option to make sure the surrounding of the text painted white and then the text is drawn in black. The only caveat is that if you have a multi-coloured background (i.e., something with gradient), it will not look as nice.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
        \node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
        \draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway,fill=white]{$f$} (v2);
        \node at (-2,1.4) {*};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another solution is to use `xshift=-1em, yshift=1em` options.

[image: Output 2]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
        \node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
        \draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway, xshift=-1em, yshift=1em]{$f$} (v2);
        %\node at (-2,1.4) {*};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you this is the best for me!

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your question with `tikz-cd`, why don't you use it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
&B\\
A\ar[ur, "f"]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to draw commutative diagrams a lot so writing everything manually would be painful. I have been using TikzEdt so far, but it seems to me you can't do tikz-cd in it?

Comment: @MaxWell TikzEdt is no more maintained. If you would like something automatic, use something like https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/ or Overleaf: https://overleaf.com or other editors.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question is that you want the label be shifted along an orthogonal line of the connection. This is what the built in `edge label` provides you with. Otherwise, this can be achieved either by determining the slope by eyes or writing a style that measures the slope. Since the slope in this case is 45 degrees, the anchor must be at `45-90=-45`. With above it will be at `-90` (modulo upside down flips). With an `edge label` this is automatic. Nonetheless it might be worthwhile to recalculate this with `calc` to convince ourselves that it is so.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Midlabel/.style={to path={
  let \p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
  in (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) node[midway,circle,anchor=\n1-90]{#1}
  }}]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L]
 \node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
 \node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
 \draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway,above]{$f$} (v2);
 \node at (-2,1.4) {*};
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=M,xshift=4cm]
 \node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
 \node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
 \draw [->] (v1) -- node[midway,anchor=-45]{$f$} (v2);
 \node at (-2,1.4) {*};
\end{scope}  
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=R,xshift=8cm]
 \node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
 \node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
 \draw[->,Midlabel={$f$}] (v1) to (v2);
 \node at (-2,1.4) {*};
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=E,xshift=12cm]
 \node (v2) at (-1,2) {$B$};
 \node (v1) at (-2.5,0.5) {$A$};
 \draw[->] (v1) to[edge label={$f$}] (v2);
 \node at (-2,1.4) {*};
\end{scope} 
\path[font=\sffamily] (L.north) node[above]{original}
 (M.north) node[above]{node anchor adjusted by hand}
 (R.north) node[above]{with \texttt{Midlabel} style}
 (E.north) node[above]{with \texttt{edge label}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As `tikz-cd` uses `edge label`s, there this is automatic. The difference comes from the fact that in the `Midlabel` style the node shape is taken to be a circle, which as evenly spread angle anchors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{Midlabel/.style={to path={
  let \p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)}
  in (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) node[midway,circle,anchor=\n1-90]{#1}
  }}}
\begin{tikzcd}
 & A \\
 B\arrow[ur,"f"] &
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
 & A \\
 B\arrow[ur,"f"]\arrow[ur,Midlabel={$\scriptstyle f$}] &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]